# How do I remove text from a list containing dictionary objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list

```
x = [{'key': 'ACT', 'value': 'Active'}, 
     {'key': 'EXP', 'value': 'Expired'}, 
     {'key': 'RCAL', 'value': 'Recall'}]
```

I want to convert it to

```
[{'ACT': 'Active', 'EXP': 'Expired', 'RCAL': 'Recall'}]
```

How do I get rid of `'key':` and `'value'` through out list x??

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> y = {a['key']: a['value'] for a in x}
>>> y
{'ACT': 'Active', 'EXP': 'Expired', 'RCAL': 'Recall'}
```

Read: [Dict Comprehensions in python.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)

Answer (score 0):

I would do list comprehension where you are creating a dictionary from each element in your list `x`:

```
x = [{'key': 'ACT', 'value': 'Active'}, 
     {'key': 'EXP', 'value': 'Expired'}, 
     {'key': 'RCAL', 'value': 'Recall'}]

x  = [{e['key']:e['value']} for e in x]

print(x)
```

This results in:

```
[{'ACT': 'Active'}, {'EXP': 'Expired'}, {'RCAL': 'Recall'}]
```

Comment: This creates multiple dictionaries with only one key-value pair item. I think the OP wants one dictionary.